# jqGrid onDelete event handler

Tags: events, jqgrid, handler, extend

I'm using a jqGrid with `datatype: 'local'`. The data of the grid is being set dynamically via `addRowData`.
I don't use the asynchronous ajax stuff such as `url` + `datatype: json` because the grid has to display only client state.

Now I want to use the jqGrid delete row functionality (`delbutton: true`), which calls the `delGridRow` function. This removes the row just fine, but of course I need to remove the underlying data. Since all of this is just client, I cannot use the `editurl`.

What I want, is a `onRowDelete` or `onRowEdited` event. But jqGrid does not support such a thing, or at least I haven't found any such thing. Implementing my own delete button would be fine, but I only managed to do this via the toolbar which isn't what I want.

After much, much fiddling I came up with the following solution to add my own event handler to jqGrid:

```
    var originalDelFunc = $.fn.jqGrid.delGridRow;
    $.fn.jqGrid.delGridRow = function (rowids, oMuligrid) {
        var onPreDeleteRowEventHandler = this.getGridParam('onPreDeleteRow'),
            consumeFlag = false;
        if (typeof onPreDeleteRowEventHandler === 'function') {
            consumeFlag = !!onPreDeleteRowEventHandler(rowids, oMuligrid);
        }

        if (!consumeFlag) {
            originalDelFunc.call(this, rowids, oMuligrid);
        }
    };
```

usage:

```
    grid.jqGrid(
        'setGridParam',
        {
            onPreDeleteRow: function(rowids, oMuligrid) {
                // remove client data here
            }
        });
```

Now, my question is: why is this so complicated? Am I missing something here? Is this solution viable, or is it likely to break with future versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote that you use `delbutton: true`. So I suppose that you use `formatter: "actions"`. The `formatter: "actions"` calls `delGridRow` on click on Delete button. I suggest that you use `afterComplete` or `afterSubmit` callbacks which second parameter contains the information about deleted row (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events2)). So I suggest you to add `formatoptions: {delOptions: {...}}` where `delOptions` includes `afterComplete` or `afterSubmit` callbacks. You should only don't forget to return `[true]` if you use `afterSubmit` callback. Such way seems me more simple as subclassing of `delGridRow` which you do.

Comment: Thanks, spot on. There is a callback after all :-)